# How to check if multiple elements are not present in a list in r

Tags: r

lets say I have this list

```
list1 = list('short'= 10,'medium'= 20,'long'=200)
```

How can I check if, for example, short and medium are not present?

Comment: What is the desired output? A single `TRUE` or `FALSE` ?

Comment: @markus it would be FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
all(c('short', 'medium') %in% names(list1))
#[1] TRUE
```

This will return `TRUE` if both `'short'` and `'medium'` is present in `list1`.

```
list1 = list('short'= 10, 'long'=200)
all(c('short', 'medium') %in% names(list1))
#[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also do

```
sum(c("short", "medium") %in% names(list1)) == length(list1)
```

#### data

```
list1 <- list('short'= 10, 'long'=200)
```